# Lip Syncing with a voice iOS development

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, mobile, voice

I am developing an iPhone app. In this app user can upload a photo of a face of his own choice. I need to move the lips of that face in sync with a voice. Please can anyone guide me in right direction? Which API should I use?

Thanks.